# C++ memory leak in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, memory-leaks

I am trying to implement a fast way of applying power operation on a matrix in C++ ( O(logn) ). Therefore I had the define the multiplication and the power operation as you can see below

```
int ** matrixmul(int ** A, int ** B, int n) {
    int ** result = (int **) calloc(sizeof(int *), n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    result[i] = (int *) calloc(sizeof(int), n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                sum += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
            result[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int ** matrixpow(int ** m, int n, int p) {
    if (p == 1) {
        return m;
    } else if (p % 2 == 0) {
        return matrixmul(matrixpow(m, n, p / 2), matrixpow(m, n, p / 2), n);
    } else {
        return matrixmul(matrixmul(matrixpow(m, n, (p - 1) / 2), matrixpow(m, n, (p - 1) / 2), n), m, n);
    }
}
```

The matrixmul function is not a generic multiplication for matrices, it's only for squared ones.

My question is if there is a way of modifying these functions so I will not have any memory leaks, because the program loses memory on each recursive call

Comment: Have you considered using `std::vector<int>` over `int*`?

Comment: `int ** result = (int **) calloc(sizeof(int *), n);` with each of these calls, you're loosing the resulting pointer of the previous call. Had you considered to use `realloc()` and pass the allocation results as a parameter?

Comment: You should create temp variables to store `matirxpow` results, pass them to `matrixmul` and free them after `matrixmul` in both `else` clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace ** with vectors and avoid using calloc, malloc, new and delete.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > result = ....
```

This will remove  problems with memory management and you can return vectors by value in C++11.

```
typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> >  Matrix;

Matrix  matrixmul(const Matrix& A, const Matrix& B, int n) {
  Matrix result(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    result[i] = std::vector<int>(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
        sum += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
      }
     result[i][j] = sum;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: So for avoiding the loss of memory your solution is to allocate the memory on the stack, not on the heap, so that the memory will be freed after the execution of the program when the destructor will be called by default? I hope I got it right. Thanks ;)

Comment: No vector allocates memory on heap. It is dectructor of vector that deletes this memory. Check about RAII (resource aquisiton is initialisation) how to wrap memory manegement in class. Vector class just handles this automaticaly.

Comment: But there is more. When you return what happens is that pointer to memory is just moved whitout copying data due to lvalue references.

Comment: Destructor is called when object gets out of scope.

Comment: Though a dedicated matrix-class (which *might* use a single vector under-the-hood, even if `unique_ptr` would be more lightweight) is probably preferable.

Comment: A dedicated matrix class could even consider `std::array<>` as a backing store.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to continue to use the `int**` for some reason, you could also make your program handle the free properly by freeing A and B before returning result in matrixmult. These are most likely the variables that are getting leaked as once matrixmult is done, you lose the ability to reference them ever again. You can free this memory pretty easily since everything is of size n throughout you code:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ) {
        free(A[i][j]);
        free(B[i][j]);
    }
    free(A[i]);
    free(B[i]);
}
```

Also this line of code seems strange:

```
int ** result = (int **) calloc(sizeof(int *), n);
```

The first parameter to calloc should be the number of elements you want and the second one should be size. I believe it should be

```
int ** result = (int **) calloc(n, sizeof(int *));
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using the C++ new/delete method of memory management instead of the C malloc/free if at all possible. It is actually typesafe and will produce more meaningful errors (actually throws an error instead of just quietly returning null). If you're going to use C++, go all in!

Comment: using new and delete is also sign of bad design. Such methods should be used only in low level plumbing code.

Comment: @RubixRechvin There will be leaked memory left from your soluiton though. Think about what happens to a formerly allocated block, when the function is called recursively.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ You're right, there's still a few unreleased variables that would need to be handled in the base case of the recursive function. I think this code would also benefit from using temp variables for storing the result of the recursive call as both the left and right side of matrixmult are equivalent. Having the temp variable would give you more access to handle the removal of all allocated memory.